# Prove sequence doesn't converge to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that for every "c" parameter, the following sequence doesn't converge to zero:
$$a_1=c$$
$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
  \frac{a_n}{3} - 1 & a_n\ge0\,\\
  -a_n & a_n<0\,\\
  \end{cases}$$

I really can't think of any solution, and when asking around someone suggested I use the integral test, but we didn't learn it as of now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would use contradiction and use the definition of convergence and take say $\epsilon$ to be a quarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose it converges towards $0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|a_n/3|<{1\over 6}$. Let $n>N$, if $a_n\geq 0$, it implies that $a_{n+1}={a_n}/3-1$, this implies that $|a_{n+1}|\geq 1-{1\over 6}>{1\over 3}$ contradiction.

If $a_n<0,=a_{n+1}=-a_n>0$ and the previous step shows that $|a_{n+2}|>{1\over 3}$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What made you assume that $$|\frac{a_n}{3}| < \frac{1}{6}$$?

Comment: Since $a_n$ converges towards $0$, there exists $N$: $n>N$ implies $|a_n|<1/2$, we deduce that $|a_n|/3<1/6$.